# Should I share the entire commits history when creating a new open source project?

Tags: github, open-source, collaboration

I have a few projects I'd like to share in my [GitHub Account](http://omederos.github.com/), and I've been wondering what is a good practice:

Should I push the entire repo (with **all the commits** history, since the very first one), or is a good idea to **start commiting on public in that moment** (and have only one commit the first time I share my project)?

Comment: If your project could be used by someone as a learning experience, I would suggest adding all the comments and the entire repo as is. If you think the earlier code was just garbage and your present edition is the first stable thing that works, well, just commit the stable thing and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your origin commits is well written and the version is well controlled, I think it's better to upload it. On the other hand, if you just use it as a practice and the version is a total mess, you may want just keep it for yourself.